# How to get ActiveRecord non-persistant variable to save?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to setup an attribute that isn't saved to the database but I can't work out how to change it and read the new value.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  attribute :online, :boolean, default: false
end
```

in Rails Console:

```
User.first.online = true
=> true
User.first.online
=> false
```

I'm running Ruby-on-rails 5.2.4.1 and ruby 2.4.1
https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.4.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Attributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-attribute

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. I decided to use the `attribute` method and you know that these kinds of attributes are not saved into the database. But at the same time, you expect that the attribute should be persistent? Why do not you just save it into the database? How do you think the attribute should be persistent when it is not stored in the DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line:

```
User.first
```

Creates an instance for the first user each time you call it.

```
User.first.equal?(User.first) #=> false
#          ^^^^^^
# Equality — At the Object level, returns true only if obj
# and other are the same object.
```

You're setting the `online` attribute of a different instance than the one you're reading from (although they represent the same record). Store the user in a variable. That way you're working with the same instance for both the set and get call.

```
user = User.first
user.online = true
user.online #=> true
```

Comment: You're right, and that is a helpful explanation thanks. How do I access the attribute from elsewhere in the application? Obviously I could pass the user variable but is it not possible to access it from the record? E.g. User.all.each {|s| puts s.id.to_s + s.online.to_s}

Comment: @MarkRobinson You'll have to pass the object around. Alternatives are to change the non-persistent attribute into a persistent one (create a database column for it). Or store the attribute in memory. For example in a hash in the `User` class, [here](https://gist.github.com/3limin4t0r/95def2bc97e2d2f2961386743310868f) is an example.

Comment: ^ I'm not sure if it's worth the trouble to store the data in memory. You need quite a few helpers to make it work, which clutter the class. Storing the attribute in the database is probably the better solution. If you need to reset the online status simply run `User.update_all(online: false)`. Is there a specific reason for using a non-persistent attribute?

Comment: Thanks, I'm just learning ActionCable and trying to adapt [User Appearances](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/action_cable_overview.html#example-1-user-appearances) for my app. The docs don't make it clear how they save the state for online appearance but it seems like something you wouldn't want to persist.

Comment: @MarkRobinson You might be able to check which users have an active session somehow. I don't know how to do that since I've never needed that functionality. If you can't find a solution, you can always ask another question. Be sure to include the bigger picture in your question, this often results in better answers.

Comment: I tested the storing attribute in hash code you provided and it works in development (Puma) but not in production using Passenger. Values aren't saving. Do you know why this might be?

Comment: That might have something to do with constant autoloading/reloading. Depending on your Rails version you can find the documentation [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html) for Rails 6 and [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants_classic_mode.html) for older versions. If the class reloads the hash will be reset.